# Cannot update a field on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL table:

```
video (id int, name varchar(30), view_count int)
```

I tried to run the following query on my computer:

```
update `video` set view_count = view_count + 1 where id = 1;
```

It works fine.

However, after I moved the database to another server, the above update query sometimes work, sometimes not work. It doesn't have any error message, but the value doesn't change.

I tried to run:

```
update `video` set name = 'testing', view_count = view_count + 1 where id = 1;
```

The name can be updated successfully, but the vide_count doesn't change..

Anyone know what problem it is?

Here is the output from MySQL prompt:

```
update `video` set view_count = view_count + 1 where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.13 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table video \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: video
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `video` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `view_count` int(10) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from video;
| id | name      | view_count |
|  1 | ABC       | 8510    |
```

Comment: Can you run this via the MySQL prompt and let us know the output? Or in PHP echo mysql_info(); and mysql_affected_rows(); afterwards and let us know the output?

Comment: Why the query you test in your dev environment is not the same that you do in the production environment. What happen if you run the second query in your dev?

Comment: Both queries work fine on my dev environment, and both of them do not work on production environment

Comment: Please add the display for `SHOW CREATE TABLE video \G` to this question

Comment: BTW is this environment LAMP or WAMP ??? Linux or Windows ???

Comment: added the display.
the dev environment is WAMP, production environment is LAMP.

Comment: @GuilhemHoffmann it auto-commit

Comment: Give us the select on your table

Comment: Lamp environment is case sensitive, and maybe some other configuration differences

Comment: Try to add a new record and update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM performs a full table lock on any DML (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)

If the video table is MyISAM, that should take care of this problem because only one person is allowed to have exclusive write privilege on the table executing a single DML statement, even if 1000 people are trying to execute

```
update `video` set name = 'testing', view_count = view_count + 1 where id = 1;
```

InnoDB performs [**MVCC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) around any data you are updating. Since [the default is REPEATABLE-READ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/will-these-two-queries-result-in-a-deadlock-if-executed-in-sequence/3224#3224), 1000 people may see the same value for view_count just before attempting to increment it. Thus, if DB Connection #1 sees view_count as 12, increments it, it should be 13. However, if DB Connection #2 sees view_count as 12, it wiil increment it, and be 13 AGAIN !!!

Keep in mind that I am only speculating based on multiple DB Connections attempting the exact same UPDATE query.

Comment: Thanks for your remind but that is not the problem. I tried another query: "update `video` set view_count = 100 where id = 1", which doesn't work on my production environment also..

Answer (score 0):

Check that view_count doesn t contain a null value

Comment: the view_count is not a null value